# In LISP, how do I define a function that requires three arguments that are all Strings that is NOT a list?

Tags: lisp

For example how would I do the Java equivalent of

```
public void threeArgs(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
{
blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: In Lisp you don't need to declare types.

Comment: In Common Lisp you can call `CHECK-TYPE` to test whether an argument is of a particular type.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun threeArgs (arg1 arg2 arg3) ...)

(threeArgs "x" "y" "z")
```

As Barmar says, Lisp does not do static typing.

Comment: I think that should be "does not require..."

Comment: @Vatine: Hmm. AFAIK static typing is done by some compilers, like CMUCL's Python, but is not part of any Lisp standard. So your formulation could be closer to the truth.

Comment: Yeah, both SBCL and CMU CL do a fair bit of type inferencing and optimization based on type information. However, type information is never required.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun threeArgs (arg1 arg2 arg3)
  (declare (type string arg1 arg2 arg3))
  ...)
```